# How to get index of an element being looped over in lwc?

Tags: lightning-web-components

I have a lwc:

html:

```html
    <template>
        <lightning-card>
            <template for:each={arr} for:item="child">
                <div key={arr.Index}> 
                    <lightning-input type="date" label="Date" value={date} onchange={handleDateChange}></lightning-input>
                    <lightning-input value={location} onchange={handleLocationChange} type="text" label="Location"></lightning-input>
                </div>
            </template>
        </lightning-card>
    </template>
```

js:

```js
    handleDateChange(event) {
            this.date = event.target.value;
            //want to get the index as well
        }
```

when I change the value of the inputs I need to get their index from the array they are being looped over. Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can include the index as a variable:

```
<template for:each={arr} for:item="child" for:index={index}>
  <div key={child.Index}>
    <lightning-input type="date" data-index={index} ...
```

And then:

```
handleDateChange(event) {
  this.date = event.target.value;
  //want to get the index as well
  let index = event.target.dataset.index;
}
```

Other alternatives are possible as well, but this is one of the basic setups to get the index.

Comment: thanks! that worked.